# UIVisualEffectView in a UITableViewCell breaks when deleting a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I have created a `UITableViewController` and each cell has a blur effect applied to them using `UIVisualEffectView`.  I also have a blurred background that is created in the `UITabBarViewController` that the table view is linked to.  The extra blur effect applied to each cell adds a nice touch to the UI I am designing, and it works for the most part.

**The Issue**

Everything works fine until I delete an item from the table.  Doing so causes the whole table view to appear damaged.  Everything returns to normal after the delete  animation has been completed.

I have tried applying the `UIVisualEffectView` via code and the storyboard, and the problem is consistent either way.  When using code, I apply the effect here like this:

```
// 'cell' is the cell being configured in tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
visualEffectView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.insertSubview(visualEffectView, atIndex: 0)
```

*Note:* After doing more testing, I have narrowed down the problem. When setting a cell to a clear color via the storyboard or in code using `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`, the damaged animation appears.  In fact, it does this for *any* color that has some, or complete transparency.  When there is no transparency, the issue stops, but then the background from the `UITabBarController` is no longer visible.

**My Question**

How can I fix the damaged animation while keeping a similar/same look?

And if you want to see how I added the blur to the `UITableViewController`, here it is:

```
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Sunset"))
        imageView.frame = self.view.bounds
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        view.insertSubview(imageView, atIndex: 0)

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
        view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, aboveSubview: imageView)
    }

    //...
```

And here is what damaged animation looks like on the simulator (same thing happens on a physical device too):

[image]